# How to access module's model in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have installed dektrium's yii2-user. I saw there are few models like User, UserSearch... I would like to access those models and its functions anywhere in my code and my controllers. But not sure how to do it.

I know how to call module, but not sure how to call functions within module's models. This is how I fetch module.

```
Yii::getModule('user')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use models globally like below:

```
use app\models\ModelName;
$model=new ModelName();
//rest of code
```

Or

```
use app\models\ModelName;
ModelName::find()->all(); //for example
```

The key note is that, you need to `use` correct `namespace`. For example `app\modules\moduleName\models`

Answer (score 0):

In the file that you want to access it from include the following example code
    `use dektrium\user\models\profile;`
then use it like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'client')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Profile::find()->all(),'user_id','name'))
```

Change the model needed accordingly